# How to apply 10-year average filter in R on a dataframe?

Tags: r, moving-average

How can I  run a 10-year average filter on the NBP on this dataframe?

This is the head of dataframe

```
> head(df3)
  Year         NBP
1 1850  35.454343
2 1851  4.5634543
3 1852  112.389182
4 1853  151.169251
5 1854  73.123145
6 1855  -72.309647
```

In reality I  have years from 1850 to 2100, how can I apply 10-year average filter on the NBP on this dataframe for the variable NBP and plot it temporally?

Comment: Do you mean computing the average `NBP` each ten years per row?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: I have added a possible solution, please check if that helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using `slider` package function `slide_dbl()` that allows you to create rolling variables. Here the code:

```
library(slider)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Year=1990:2020,NBP=rnorm(31,2,0.5))
# Rolling by group
df %>% 
  mutate(rollingNBP = slide_dbl(NBP, mean, .before = 9, .complete = T))
```

Output:

```
   Year       NBP rollingNBP
1  1990 1.8399718         NA
2  1991 1.3442388         NA
3  1992 1.7001958         NA
4  1993 1.9352947         NA
5  1994 2.4433681         NA
6  1995 1.9243020         NA
7  1996 2.1648956         NA
8  1997 0.3863386         NA
9  1998 1.6141041         NA
10 1999 2.1432743   1.749598
11 2000 1.3897440   1.704576
12 2001 2.2172752   1.791879
13 2002 2.4000884   1.861868
14 2003 1.9180345   1.860142
15 2004 2.6214594   1.877952
16 2005 1.5328075   1.838802
17 2006 2.1968543   1.841998
18 2007 2.2018157   2.023546
19 2008 1.5567816   2.017813
20 2009 1.3405312   1.937539
21 2010 2.0144220   2.000007
22 2011 1.7839351   1.956673
23 2012 2.8449363   2.001158
24 2013 2.6141964   2.070774
25 2014 2.1380117   2.022429
26 2015 1.4755122   2.016700
27 2016 1.7395653   1.970971
28 2017 2.8116013   2.031949
29 2018 1.4649659   2.022768
30 2019 2.8429436   2.173009
31 2020 1.8791551   2.159482
```

If you want to include a plot, you can use `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code2
df %>% 
  mutate(rollingNBP = slide_dbl(NBP, mean, .before = 9, .complete = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=rollingNBP))+
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]

And if you want to see both series, try this:

```
library(tidyr)
#Code 3
df %>% 
  mutate(rollingNBP = slide_dbl(NBP, mean, .before = 9, .complete = F)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=value,group=name,color=name))+
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you kindly tell what does .before = 9 stand for?

Comment: @HallieSheikh For sure, it is the number of rows before, instead of using `k=10` as in other functions, you set `.before = 9` in the slider function to tell it that the rolling is with ten elements. I hope that was clear for you. You can play with different values.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, if I want to temporally plot the dataframe after I applied the 10 year average filter, how can I do it? Should i go with plot(df$Year,df$NBP)?

Comment: @HallieSheikh Let me add some code for the plot of the new variable.

Comment: @HallieSheikh I have added two ways for plotting the series. I hope that can be useful for you!!!

Comment: thank you. I would like to know that is it possible to make a data frame of year and only rollingNBP values?

Comment: @HallieSheikh Yes, I think you refer to this: `newdata <- df %>% 
  mutate(rollingNBP = slide_dbl(NBP, mean, .before = 9, .complete = F))`

Answer (score 1):

An option with `rollmean` from `zoo`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
    mutate(rollingNBP = rollmeanr(NBP, k = 10, fill = NA))
```